# In c++ seekg seems to include cr chars, but read() drops them

Tags: c++, newline, ifstream

I'm currently trying to read the contents of a file into a char array.

For instance, I have the following text in a char array. 42 bytes:

```
{
    type: "Backup",
    name: "BackupJob"
}
```

This file is created in windows, and I'm using Visual Studio c++, so there is no OS compatibility issues.

However, executing the following code, at the completion of the for loop, I get Index: 39, with no 13 displayed prior to the 10's.

```
// Create the file stream and open the file for reading
ifstream fs;
fs.open("task.txt", ifstream::in);

int index = 0;
int ch = fs.get();
while (fs.good()) {
    cout << ch << endl;
    ch = fs.get();
    index++;
}

cout << "----------------------------";
cout << "Index: " << index << endl;
return;
```

However, when attempting to create a char array the length of the file, reading the file size as per below results in the 3 additional CR chars attributing to the total filesize so that `length` is equal 42, which is adding screwing up the end of the array with dodgy bytes.

```
// Create the file stream and open the file for reading
ifstream fs;
fs.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
length = fs.tellg();
fs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

// Create the buffer to read the file
char* buffer = new char[length];
fs.read(buffer, length);
buffer[length] = '\0';
// Close the stream
fs.close();
```

Using a hex viewer, I have confirmed that file does indeed contain the CRLF (13 10) bytes in the file.

There seems to be a disparity with getting the end of the file, and what the get() and read() methods actually return.

Could anyone please help with this?

Cheers, 
Justin

Comment: When DOS was invented they said lines end with CR LF.  But then C became popular and said lines end with '\n'.  To accommodate the two formats, C IO routines have text and binary modes.

Comment: @brianbeuning The use of CRLF goes back long before DOS (or Unix).  It's the character sequence required by the ancient teletypes: CR brought the head back to position 0, without advancing a line, and LF advanced a line, leaving the head where it was.  (In principle, you could use either CRLF or LFCR.  But for technical reasons, CRLF was faster, so became almost universal.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should open your file in binary mode. This will stop read dropping CR.

```
fs.open("task.txt", ifstream::in|ifstream::binary);
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Now i'm off to read all about that. Had me stumped for quite some time :) Thank you very much

Comment: But since he's reading text, why should he use binary mode.  The representation of a new line is implementation defined, and he shouldn't worry about it.  (And of course, seeking to the end of the file, and then using `tellg`, is _not_ a portable way of getting the size of the file, in any case.)

Comment: OK, so what would a portable way to determine the length of a file?

Comment: @Juzzbott, read the whole file, counting the bytes as you read, is the only portable way. In practice everyone does what you are doing.